# Small Piezo Buzzers

Tags: components, piezoelectricity

I am looking to get my hands on some Pizeo Buzzers that are as small as possible.  So far I have found [10mm round](http://parts.digikey.com/1/parts/338-buzzer-piezo-element-7-0khz-10mm-ab1070b.html), which is good, but I was wondering if anyone knew of ones that are smaller still?

I would prefer to avoid SMD components if at all possible, but I can deal with it if need be.  At the end of the day, as small as 5x5mm would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Pizeo Buzzer with **6.5 mm** here:

1. [PDF with specifications](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/700000-724999/710385-an-01-en-PIEZOELEMENT_EPZ_20MS64W.pdf)
2. [The item in a shop](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/710385/PIEZOELEMENT-EPZ-20MS64W/0235311&ref=list)

Comment: excellent!  A mite pricey, but I guess small things usually are.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: While sound pressure depends on the surface the piezo is mounted on, a piezo this small won't be very loud. And the resonance frequency is 7kHz, which is a bit high (ears are less sensitive to it)

Comment: The second link appears to be to a 20mm piezo.